# HLSL projection shader

Tags: direct3d, hlsl

I am  rendering a scene to a texture and then drawing a water plane with that texture using projection. Most of the samples I have seen on the web pass in a view/projection matrix to the vertex shader and transform the vertex, then in the pixel shader they do :

```
projection.x = input.projectionCoords.x / input.projectionCoords.w / 2.0 + 0.5;
projection.y = input.projectionCoords.y / input.projectionCoords.w / 2.0 + 0.5;
```

I have a shader that does the following and it works too but I don't know where I found this particular code or how it gives the same results with the above code. Here is the code I have

Vertex shader : (world is an identityMatrix, viewProj is my cameras combined viewProjection matrix):

```
output.position3D =  mul(float4(vsin.position,1.0), world).xyz;
output.position = mul(float4(output.position3D,1.0), viewProj);

output.reflectionTexCoord.x = 0.5 * (output.position.w + output.position.x);
output.reflectionTexCoord.y = 0.5 * (output.position.w - output.position.y);
output.reflectionTexCoord.z = output.position.w;
```

Pixel shader :

```
float2 projectedTexCoord = (input.reflectionTexCoord.xy / input.reflectionTexCoord.z);
```

What confuses me is the usage of `0.5 * (output.position.w + output.position.x)` and `0.5 * (output.position.w - output.position.y)`. How does this have the same effect and what does the w component mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while I realized that it ends up being the same thing :

```
0.5 * (output.position.w + output.position.x);

0.5 * output.position.w + 0.5 * output.position.x
```

Then in the pixel shader :

```
(0.5 * output.position.w + 0.5 * output.position.x) / output.position.w

(0.5 * output.position.w)/output.position.w + (0.5 * output.position.x) / output.position.w
```

The first part becomes 0.5 :

```
0.5 + 0.5 * ( output.position.x / output.position.w)
```

This is equal to :

```
(output.position.x / output.position.w) / 2 + 0.5
```

I believe moving this calculation to the vertex shader is more efficient so I will just leave it there.

To completely move the calculation out of the shader the matrix can be calculated on the client side :

```
XMMATRIX v = XMLoadFloat4x4(&view);
XMMATRIX p = XMLoadFloat4x4(&projection);

XMMATRIX t(
    0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

XMMATRIX reflectionTransform = v * p * t;
XMStoreFloat4x4(&_reflectionTransform, XMMatrixTranspose(reflectionTransform));
```

Then all the vertex shader has to do is :

```
output.reflectionTexCoord = mul(float4(output.position3D,1.0), reflectionProjectionMatrix);
```